# Remove dictionaries from list

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
items = [{'item': 1}, {'item': 2}, {'item': 3}]
```

How can I convert it to this?

```
items = [1, 2, 3]
```

This is my current solution but I wonder if there is a better one

```
items = [item['item'] for item in items]
```

Comment: @SandeepKadapa It won't work because `items` is a list in the first place

Comment: It's a *Python*ic way (list comprehension) of doing things. You want a better solution from what point of view?

Comment: What kind of 'better' do you expect?

Comment: I guess the OP is looking for some kind of mapping or iterator tools. I wonder why not stick to the current solution

Comment: You can also use `map(lambda d: d['value'], yourlist)` . Map and lambda functions here

Comment: @CristiFati I have not been programming in python that long, so I thought there might be a simpler solution.

Comment: This is the simplest I could think of though...

Comment: List comprehensions are replacing map+lambda in terms of simplicity and readability, so IMO your original code is the best way.

Comment: what's wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right, you could only improve your code using `get()` method:

```
items = [item.get('item', 'default') for item in items]
```

Which provides you with argument for default value for cases that don't have the `item` key.

This would be the example:

```
items = [{'item': 1}, {'item': 2}, {'item': 3}, {'noitem': 4}]
[item.get('item', 'default') for item in items]
#[1, 2, 3, 'default']
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is better than your solution, but you can use [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
import operator
map(operator.itemgetter('item'), items)
```

In python 3.x you need to cast the result into a `list` though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution which I did on the interactive shell that you can implement it to your code.

```
>>> a = []
>>> for i in items:
...     a.append(i['item'])
... 
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Well without explicitly having to call the item with `item`, this means that the key of the dictionary could be anything, you can use this:

```
items = [{'item': 1}, {'item': 2}, {'item': 3}]
new_items = []
for item in items:
  for value in item.values():
    items.append(value)
items = new_items[:]
```

UPDATE:
As [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) suggested a list on comprehension could accomplish the same:

```
items = [v for d in items for v in d.values()]
```

Comment: That's... awfully verbose. `items = [v for d in items for v in d.values()]` would achieve the same in less.

Comment: Yes it does achieve the same in less but not always less is better. I personally dislike complicated lists of comprehension with nested for loops. But thanks for the alternative. I'll update the post for a better view of your alternative.